# Is there a word for artificial language except programming languages?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for artificial language except programming languages? Non-natural languages for human-to-human communication?

Comment: The term I've encountered most often is "constructed languages"

Comment: Are programming languages called ‘artificial languages’? I’ve only heard it used in the context of linguistic experiments.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle I'm just a layman with an interest in linguistics, so my use of terms might be wrong, sorry. I get downvotes frequently on linguistics stackexchange and I already got one for this too, now I'm in danger of being blocked! Is this question obviously bad when seen by experienced users here? Is it because it's too random? I've been thinking about something related and was curious about this. I thought it'd take a layman a lot of time to find the right technical terms whereas linguists might know it already, so I casually post questions... Or is non-natural language off-topic?

Comment: I'm only asking in general, not complaining. Others likely know more.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle I'm new to here, so I'm not sure about the norm here, so I just asked if my question come off as an okay one to people here including you. About half of the new questions on this page http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/unanswered got 1 to 3 downvotes. Does this happen all the time here? I think I'll try to do more research before asking if that's the norm, but if I'm just getting random downvotes now, I can keep posting casually so I asked.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. The standard term of art is "conlang", short for "constructed language". Conlangs are further divided into numerous more specific categories like philosophical languages, artistic languages (artlangs), logical languages (loglangs), engineered languages (engelangs), auxiliary languages (auxlangs), and so forth. Where applicable, they can also be categorized by the natural language family from which they take inspiration, as in romlangs (artificial romance languages, generally the most popular of this sort), germlangs (artificial germanic languages) and slavlangs (artificial slavic languages).